# Is there a capacity-restricted queue object in Java that is accessible from both ends?

Tags: java, queue, containers

I was thinking something the likes of `java.util.ArrayBlockingQueue`, which enables you to create size-limited queues. But that would have methods to retrieve and and add elements from both sides (head or tail).
Kind of like Perl arrays which have `push`/`pop` and `shift`/`unshift` methods.

I can probably roll my own but if something already exists out there I'd like to know.

Answer (score 2):

There certainly is, the [LinkedBlockingDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html).

Comment: Excellent. It most certainly is -> though what would be even better would be if it would auto remove elements from opposite side when adding over the capacity. But for now LinkedBlockingDequeu shoud do fine by me.